# Get selected string from TextMeshPro input field/text on Android

Tags: unity, android, text-mesh-pro

i am trying to create a tag system for a journal i'm making and that requires being able to select specific parts from either an input field or a text element with the finger (drag and select) and then save that selection into a list.

The issue is i don't know how to do it! i did some google research in terms of "saving selected text from input fields" and similar searches but i couldn't find something to help me out.

The flow should be : user types something like "hello world" , then he drags his finger on the screen highlighting the word "World" and once highlighted it is saved into an empty string which then i can add to the list i want.

Can i get some help or recommendations on what to read to make it happen?
Thank you!

Comment: The Text Mesh Pro documentation shows API methods to get the character index where the selection starts and the length of the selection, if I recall correctly, and [an event fired when the selection is completed](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.TextSelectionEvent.html) — have you tried using these?

Comment: no as a matter of fact i didnt know that! i did take a look at it but i dont know how to use it, its a class right? do i need other events?

Comment: @stratosla have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with mobile yet. But you can find the selection something like:

```
int start = your_inputfield.selectionAnchorPosition;

int end~ = your_inputfield.selectionStringFocusPosition;
```

From there you would want a context popup or something with a button to save selection.

```
tmp_inputfield.selectionAnchorPosition {Get; Set;}

tmp_inputfield.selectionStringFocusPosition {Get; Set;}
```

The two properties of `tmp_inputfield` can be treated like variables if you are unfamiliar.